# How to set tycho version number for eclipse plugin built

Tags: eclipse-plugin, version, pom.xml, tycho

I have a question about setting tycho version number before building your app.

I have set

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
                <artifactId>tycho-versions-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${tycho.version}</version>
            </plugin>
```

this under my master pom file in my app,

and run

```
mvn tycho-versions:set-version -DnewVersion=1.0.2.qualifier
```

I think that it is easy, but I got an error:

```
 Failed to execute goal org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-versions-plugin:2.2.0:set-version (default-cli) on project de.xxxx: Execution default-cli of goal org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-versions-plugin:2.2.0:set-version failed: This Pom <project-path>\.polyglot.META-INF is in the Wrong Format: No root element found
```

I have googled all the time, but no solution found.

maybe you had also the same problem?

Comment: Did you follow https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseTycho/article.html#defining-a-specialized-pom-file-for-an-eclipse-component and https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseTycho/article.html#setting-version-numbers ? What do you need it for? In most cases, with POM-less Tycho this should not be necessary at all. What's your `${tycho.version}`?

Comment: I just want to set version before building. what do you mean that it is not necessary ?

Comment: How shold I set plugin in master pom?

Comment: From my understanding, the reason `tycho-versions-plugin` exists is to keep the version in the POM file in sync with the version in `MANIFEST.MF`, `feature.xml`, etc. Using POM-less Tycho you might have only one parent POM with a version that does not matter.

Comment: yes, that is my goal, that pom file is in sync with the version in mainfest and feature. I have only one parent pom.